# Multidimensional Arrays in Swift with Different Datatype & Fill it Dynamically

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

How do I dynamically create a Multidimensional `Array` in Swift iOS? Something like this:

```
var array = [["A", false, 0], ["B", false, 1], ["C", false, 2], ["D", false, 3]]
```

I want to store 3 Datatypes `String`, `Boolean` and `Integer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2D array with different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725888/swift-2d-array-with-different-types)

Answer (score 0):

`Array` type not allow you to store elements of different type. You better make some data structure for elements of such array. For example:

```
struct Data {
    let letter: String
    let condition: Bool
    let id: Int
    init(_ letter: String, _ condition: Bool, _ id: Int) {
        self.letter = letter
        self.condition = condition
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Then you can declare array like this:

```
let array: [Data] = [Data("A", false, 0), Data("B", false, 1), Data("C", false, 2), Data("D", false, 3)]
```

If you *really* need to use plane types, you should use `Any` (or `AnyObject`) type:

```
let array: [[Any]] = [["A", false, 0], ["B", false, 1], ["C", false, 2], ["D", false, 3]]
```

but you will be faced with casting types every time then

Comment: var array = [["A", false, 0], ["B", false, 1], ["C", false, 2], ["D", false, 3]] this syntax is right but i want to fill data in this type of array dynamically. First declare a structure for such an array and then fill data in that array dynamically